# Python - Remove All Occurences Of A Substring Within A String

Tags: python, string, recursion, substring

There are 2 main rules of note for the function I am trying to make:

- > 1. No use of modules are allowed
- > 2. The substring must be obtained by a 'begin' and 'end' string.

The aim is to take a base, begin, and end string. Then, remove all text between those strings. This has to be for each occurrence, not just the first.

eg:
base is *"yes_and_no___yes_and_no"*,
begin is *"yes"*,
end is *"no"*

output: *"yesno___yesno"*

This is my code so far, however it only works for the first occurrence. Would a recursive implementation be ideal?

```
def extractFromString(baseStr, extStr1, extStr2):
    if extStr1 and extStr2 in baseStr:
        # >1. Get start/end indices
        start = baseStr.find(extStr1) + len(extStr1)
        end = baseStr.find(extStr2)
        
        # >2. Get first/second halves
        firstHalf = baseStr[:start]
        secondHalf = baseStr[end:]

        # >3. Combine and return
        result = firstHalf + secondHalf
        return result
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a problem with your `if`. `if extStr1 and extStr2 in baseStr` doesn't do what you think it does. You need to check if *each substring* is in the base string *individually* like `if extStr1 in baseStr and extStr2 in baseStr`

Instead of using loops or recursion, I'd suggest using regular expressions and [`re.sub()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub)

First, we build a regex to match `yes`, then as few of any character as possible, and then `no`: `yes.*?no` [Try it](https://regex101.com/r/ydIiTo/3)

Remember to [`escape()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.escape) the input strings in case they contain special characters.

Next, we replace all occurrences of this regex with `yesno`.

```
import re

def extractFromString(baseStr, extStr1, extStr2):
    rexp = re.compile(f"{re.escape(extStr1)}.*?{re.escape(extStr2)}")
    return re.sub(rexp, extStr1 + extStr2, baseStr)
```

Running this with a bunch of inputs

```
extractFromString("yes_and_no___yes_and_no", "yes", "no")
# Output: 'yesno___yesno'

extractFromString("aha_no_yes_deleteThis_no_no_no_yes", "yes", "no")
# Output: 'aha_no_yesno_no_no_yes'

extractFromString("yes_yes_aha_no_no_yes_no_no", "yes", "no")
# Output: 'yesno_no_yesno_no'

extractFromString("yes_yes_no_no", "yes", "no")
# Output: 'yesno_no'
```

Comment: This is a great solution and I'm sure will help anybody that stumbles upon this post. However, I am tasked specifically not to use any modules. The original purpose of the task is to remove any text between '<script>' and '</script>' from a given HTML file

Answer (score 0):

```
extStr1 = "yes"
extStr2 = "no"

def extractFromString(baseStr, extStr1, extStr2):
    if extStr1 in baseStr and extStr2 in baseStr:
        # >1. Get start/end indices
        start = baseStr.find(extStr1) + len(extStr1)
        end = baseStr.find(extStr2, start)
        if end == -1:
            return baseStr
        processStr = baseStr[:end+len(extStr2)]
        queueStr = baseStr[end+len(extStr2):]

        firstHalf = processStr[:start]
        secondHalf = processStr[end:]
        processStr = firstHalf + secondHalf

        return processStr + extractFromString(queueStr, extStr1, extStr2)
    else:
        return baseStr

for exampleStr in exampleStrs:
    print("input:")
    print(exampleStr)
    print("output:")
    print(extractFromString(exampleStr, extStr1, extStr2))
    print("\n")
```

gives the following output:

```
input:
yes_and_no___yes_and_no
output:
yesno___yesno


input:
aha_no_yes_deleteThis_no_no_no_yes
output:
aha_no_yesno_no_no_yes


input:
yes_yes_aha_no_no_yes_no_no
output:
yesno_no_yesno_no


input:
yes_yes_no_no
output:
yesno_no
```

this is done by splitting the string and recursively calling the function.
Check for the last example if this is the behaviour you want tho.

Answer (score -1):

You can split the base string at every occurrence of your *extStr2* first and then split it at the occurrence of *extStr1*

```
def extractFromString(baseStr, extStr1, extStr2):
    final_str= ""
    if extStr1 and extStr2 in baseStr:
        base_subStr= baseStr.split(extStr2) 
        for index in range(0,len(base_subStr)):
            if extStr1 not in base_subStr[index]:   
                final_str= final_str + base_subStr[index]
            else:
                final_str= final_str + base_subStr[index].split(extStr1)[0] + extStr2
```

I haven't run this, but this might work for your case

Comment: `if extStr1 and extStr2 in baseStr` doesn't do what you think it does

Comment: Also doesn't work because `base_subStr[index].split(extStr1)` is a list that you're trying to concat to a string. Throws a typeerror